# getting specific field from shopify prodcts api

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, shopify, shopify-app

I'm using `FastAPI` and I created a wrapper for the `shopify` products API, I'm trying to get the product title, id, and image src ! in case the product has a lot of images I wanna return a list of images SRCs  :

```
GET  https://APIKEY:password@koldev.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?title={product_name}&fields=id,title,images
```

this way everything works but i get all the info of the images , SO is there any way to get only the src ??

this is the response i get :

```
{"products":[{"id":5845888762006,"title":"2WAYボタンニット・全2色・e56772","images":[{"id":19588495999126,"product_id":5845888762006,"position":1,"created_at":"2020-10-21T02:13:26-04:00","updated_at":"2020-10-21T02:13:33-04:00","alt":null,"width":750,"height":1030,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0446/9450/3574/products/867976_17469854_main.jpg?v=1603260813","variant_ids":[],"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid://shopify/ProductImage/19588495999126"},{"id":19588496359574,"product_id":5845888762006,"position":2,"created_at":"2020-10-21T02:13:26-04:00","updated_at":"2020-10-21T02:13:33-04:00","alt":null,"width":1000,"height":3768,"src":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0446/9450/3574/products/867976_17467030_k2.jpg?v=1603260813","variant_ids":[],"admin_graphql_api_id":"gid://shopify/ProductImage/19588496359574"}
```

API :

```
@app.get('/products')
def get_searched_products(product_name: Optional[str] = None):
        
        r = requests.get(
f"https://APIKEY:password@koldev.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?title={product_name}&fields=id,title,images")
        
        return r.json()
```

Comment: Do you want to know the schema necessary to omit the remaining data? I don't fully get it what you want.

Comment: i wanna know what to add in the url or in the response to get only the images src ( i already got the title and the id ) ( i edited the post )

Comment: the way to do this is using graphql instead of rest api

Answer (score 1):

I've created a self-contained app with a single endpoint and a test it, you can run with `pytest <filename>`

```py
from typing import List, Optional

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


app = FastAPI()


class ImageSrcOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str
    images: List[dict]

    @validator("images")
    def validate_images(cls, value: List[dict]) -> List[str]:
        return [element["src"] for element in value]


@app.get("/products", response_model=List[ImageSrcOut])
def get_searched_products(product_name: Optional[str] = None):
    res = {
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 5845888762006,
                "title": "2WAYボタンニット・全2色・e56772",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": 19588495999126,
                        "product_id": 5845888762006,
                        "position": 1,
                        "created_at": "2020-10-21T02:13:26-04:00",
                        "updated_at": "2020-10-21T02:13:33-04:00",
                        "alt": None,
                        "width": 750,
                        "height": 1030,
                        "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0446/9450/3574/products/867976_17469854_main.jpg?v=1603260813",
                        "variant_ids": [],
                        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/19588495999126",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 19588496359574,
                        "product_id": 5845888762006,
                        "position": 2,
                        "created_at": "2020-10-21T02:13:26-04:00",
                        "updated_at": "2020-10-21T02:13:33-04:00",
                        "alt": None,
                        "width": 1000,
                        "height": 3768,
                        "src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0446/9450/3574/products/867976_17467030_k2.jpg?v=1603260813",
                        "variant_ids": [],
                        "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductImage/19588496359574",
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    }

    # return res.json()
    return res["products"]


client = TestClient(app)


def test_right_json():
    res = client.get("/products")
    assert res.json() == [
        {
            "id": 5845888762006,
            "title": "2WAY\u30dc\u30bf\u30f3\u30cb\u30c3\u30c8\u30fb\u51682\u8272\u30fbe56772",
            "images": [
                "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0446/9450/3574/products/867976_17469854_main.jpg?v=1603260813",
                "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0446/9450/3574/products/867976_17467030_k2.jpg?v=1603260813",
            ],
        }
    ]
```

Notes: You need to install: `fastapi`, `requests` and `pytest` to run it.

Comment: Yes this may works in this case but when I change that the res from that format to the same way I did in the post I get an error saying that the response in not a list  , can you adapt the api that I posted to yours?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want. I've used the same output you had in the description because I didn't want to create an account on Shopify to get the token...